Restrict monitoring scope on Azure for Grafana
I'm trying to monitor Azure resources (mainly managed SQL servers) through The Azure monitor Grafana plug-in. It works if I assign Monitor Reader permissions on the subscription scope to the grafana service principal, but fails if I try to restrict the role assignment to the resource group level.
I don't want a Grafana application to be able to access the whole subscription. Whe restrictuing permissions, the datasource seems to pass the test correctly, but then when trying to query a resource in the Explore section of Grafana, I get the error "Unable to resolve a list of valid metric namespaces. Validate the datasource configuration is correct and required permissions have been granted for all subscriptions. Grafana requires at least the Reader role to be assigned.". This is probably because the Azure monitor plug-in for Grafana expects to be able to read the whole subscription data.
Has anyone solved this?

It should be enough to add the role "Monitoring Data Reader" on the "Monitor Workspace" to the service principal from the grafana.
So grafna can access the Monitor Workspace.
The get collected from the monitor workspace with the data collection rules.
